# win32 api function to get processor's current speed

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am unaware of a win32 api function/functions used to query the local PC processor's current speed. I wish not to use WMI because it seems unlikely to be feasible on all PCs.

Comment: Hi Sesame! This question is a bit vague, but hopefully someone may help.

Comment: What versions of windows are you targeting? WMI's availability depends only on the version of Windows in use, I'd think...

Comment: There's no API function to do this. Even WMI can give inaccurate values for the processor clock speed. The best program that I'm aware of for getting the clock speed is CPUz.

Comment: Here's a link, example uses Perl - http://search.cpan.org/~cjohnston/Win32-SystemInfo-0.11/SystemInfo.pm

Comment: The CPU speed varies rapidly with current work load, potentially changing many times per second: what kind of resolution to this monitoring do you want? What makes you think WMI won't work on some PCs?

Comment: +1: Good question; it seems non-trivial to answer this, and I couldn't find another question on here which asks for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (usually) get the processor speed using the [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. I'm saying "usually" since this function returns the frequency of the performance timer component of the system, but virtually all current CPU's available operate at the same frequency as the performance timer component.

This function is available since Windows 2000, so chances are good that it's supported on most of todays PCs.

Comment: "virtually all current CPU's available operate at the same frequency as the performance timer component." The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx) claims: "In many cases, QueryPerformanceFrequency returns the TSC frequency divided by 1024; and on Hyper-V, the performance counter frequency is always 10 MHz when the guest virtual machine runs under a hypervisor that implements the hypervisor version 1.0 interface." It seems the "divided by 1024" case is true for my system, in particular. So this doesn't seem too reliable :(

Comment: The frequency of the performance counter is constant and not varying according to the CPU clock

Answer (score 19):

You can call the Windows API function [CallNtPowerInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the argument ProcessorInformation.  It returns a [PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure which tells you the current and max CPU speed for each of your system's CPUs.

This is only supported on Win32 desktop, not Metro or Windows Phone, though.

Comment: Excellent! NOTE: The structure definition is still missing from headers, even though Microsoft promised 20 yrs ago: *"This error will be corrected in the future. In the meantime, to compile your application, include the structure definition contained in this topic in your source code"*

Comment: Have a look at my answer: CallNtPowerInformation( PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION ... ) gives the base clock of the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You [read it from the registry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/netfxbcl/thread/87CDA2F2-015E-4AEC-BCA0-7E259F9AA01F) using the [usual registry functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875.aspx)

Comment: You can only get the base clock from the registry.