# C# Current Clock Speed Display

Tags: c#, cpu

I'm trying to get my c# App to show the current clock speed of my CPU. It kind of works but the Speed stays the same even though in Task Manager the Clock Speed is Higher or Lower. Here is my code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher ClockSpeedSearch = new 
ManagementObjectSearcher("select CurrentClockSpeed from Win32_Processor");


foreach (var item in ClockSpeedSearch.Get())
{
  var clockSpeed = (uint)item["CurrentClockSpeed"];
CPUClockSpeed.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>  CPUClockSpeed.Text =  "CPU Clock Speed: " + clockSpeed + "Mhz"));
}
```

The Clock speed stays at 2808Mhz and will not change... Can Anyone help me with this??

***UPDATE***
I found out what I had to do but now I get the System.InvalidOperationException: Category does not exist error. See my screenshot 
[here](http://prntscr.com/jslm34)

Best Regards
Dylan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22646098/2701753 perhaps

Comment: You can use the PerformanceCounters https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter to get that info. If you open up Windows Perf Mon you can add `ProcessorPerformance\frequency` on a per-core basis. Perf Mon is a GUI for the performance counters. I don't have the time to write that up as an actual answer sorry.

Comment: Well I found what I had to do except it now gives me an error saying: "System.InvalidOperationException: Category Does Not Exist"

Comment: The WMI provider is written by programmers that are relentlessly honest.  The processor dynamically increases its clock frequency as long as it has some code to run and the chip does not get too hot.  You do have code to run, your WMI query.  Standard Heisenberg.  So they don't lie to you, you get the *nominal* speed.  It can ramp up to the value returned by MaxClockSpeed, likely to be the current value as long as you don't run that query too often :)  Digging out the processor performance counter is gritty but boring, you'll just get the value you already know.  Move on to the next project.

Comment: My project is making a Hardware monitor on an Arduino. How come OpenHardwareMonitor can see the current clock speed e.g. 3.6Ghz 3.4Ghz etc. But with the performance monitor and the same code that I used for CPU Load mine can't?? I typed everything correctly and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that this information is not updated very often (if at all post BIOS).

This page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 (search for CurrentClockSpeed) suggests the information is from the [System Management BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS)

> Current speed of the processor, in MHz.
>
> > This value comes from the Current Speed member of the Processor Information structure in the SMBIOS information.

Answer (score 0):

This information is from processor driver, and this value is not fixed. if you put heavy loading on your system, then get it again. you will get different values comparing with system idle. hope this information useful for you.